# Sharepoint Microsoft Graph API limit

Tags: api, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to make a an application that will use the Microsoft graph API to connect to Sharepoint to do various tasks.

Recently I have found that there is a throttling/blocking limit for the API, see: [Microsoft Documentation Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online)

Now I have some questions I want to clarify,
if I have a tenant that contains an app that calls more than 6000 calls/min "the maximum allowable limit".

- would it just throttle for the remaining of the minute then continue normally after or what?
- can I do anything to exceed that limit? "contacting support, bigger license, etc."
- can I bypass this limit by creating multiple apps instead of one and splitting the load between them or is this limit is tenant wise? **(is this limit per app or per tenant?)**

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#what-happens-when-you-get-throttled-in-sharepoint-online):

1. When usage limits are exceeded, SharePoint Online throttles any further requests from that client for a short period.

2.If the offending application continues to exceed usage limits, SharePoint Online may completely block the application or specific request patterns from the application; in this case, the application will keep getting HTTP status code 503, and Microsoft will notify the tenant of the block in the Office 365 Message Center.

3.Every application has its own limits in a tenant, which are based on the number of licenses purchased per organization (see the plans listed on SharePoint Limits for licenses included). Every request that an application makes across all API endpoints, including Microsoft Graph, CSOM and REST, counts towards the application’s usage.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the table demonstrates that the increase in the number of calls a tenant is proportionate to the number of licenses the tenant currently has.

1. On the first question, generally, if your apps exceed the amount of calls that SharePoint allows, it would return an error.
2. You are correct in that you can contact Microsoft and seek extra licenses, which will incur additional costs.
3. To avoid this problem, you can add sleep time to your apps to impelent batching of calls.